# How can I cast specific part of string type query to date to avoid "ORA-01843: not a valid month" error?

Tags: c#, oracle, casting

So I am trying to backup failed queries when the database is down and execute them immediately after database is ready. So far I am saving all the failed queries in text file. When the database is up I execute those failed queries line by line from the file. Since those failed queries are stored in string format, when I execute them for Oracle database (one column's datatype is date) I get ORA-01843: not a valid month. 
e.g

```
INSERT INTO my_table ("MODULE", "USERNAME", "COMPUTER", "DATE","NAME", "EMAIL" ) values ('mymodule', 'mmouse', 'mickey007', '06-03-2015 12:05:00', 'Mickey Mouse', 'mmickey@gmail.com')
```

Since there is going to be a lot of this kind queries in the fail_queries file what could be the ways to cast just '06-03-2015 12:05:00' part of string to date

Thanks beforehand!!!

Comment: Use [TO_DATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php). You need to define a (datetime) format.

Comment: do you mean searching for dd-mm-yyyy hh-mi-sec format in every string and casting it? is it actually possible to cast just one part of string?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from your code behind?

Comment: @Greg yes exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pass `DateTime` as string, instead use Parameters.

If you have to pass a string then you have to convert it to date using [`TO_DATE`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0260__Date-Timestamp-Functions/TODATEwithINSERTstatement.htm) like in your case:

```
TO_DATE('06-03-2015 12:05:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

But, if you are sending values through C#, then **instead of concatenating values, use Parameters.**  like:

```
using(OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("yourConnectionString"))
using (
    OracleCommand command =
        new OracleCommand(@"INSERT INTO my_table (MODULE, USERNAME, COMPUTER, DATE,NAME, EMAIL ) 
           values (:myModule, :mmouse,:mickey007, :myDateTime,:myothercol, :myEmail", connection))
{
    //add parameters
    command.Parameters.Add(":myModule", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "myModule";
    command.Parameters.Add(":myDateTime", OracleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now; // like this
    //add other parameters similarly. 
    connection.Open();
    //execute command

}
```

Parameters will not only save you from errors like these, but also save you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Was about to answer, but no need now.

Comment: I can't hard code it, since same application executes queries for different tables as well. I execute queries as you said when the database is up. When it goes down I store them in text file and execute them whenever the database become ready to use. I don't want to store both commandText and paramaters for each query.